# Can you identify these Doctors of the science fiction genre in miniature formats?

Tags: comics, character-identification, science-fiction-genre

#### Please identify these Doctors, their minions, their comic or science fiction genre of origin and links, if possible.

[image]

Comment: [Doc Brown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmett_Brown) is missing from this VIP line-up :'-(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[image]

1. [Doctor Leonard McCoy](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Leonard_McCoy), *Star Trek*, apparently [from this set](http://img.trekmovie.com/images/merchandise/pmst09/12inch_Star_Trek_5_figs_t.jpg)
2. ***possibly*** [The Fourth Doctor](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Fourth_Doctor), *Doctor Who*, from this 2010 [Fourth Doctor & Electronic TARDIS](http://merchandise.thedoctorwhosite.co.uk/4th-doctor-classic-electronic-tardis-planet-of-evil/) figure, with the hat and scarf removed (except the hair color is off -- possible image artifact?)
3. [Doctor Stephen Strange](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Stephen_Strange_(Earth-616)), Marvel Comics, from [*Marvel Universe* Series 3](http://www.hasbro.com/en-us/product/marvel-universe-series-3-doctor-strange-figure:A7A4D335-5056-900B-100E-0C360E0EA2DB)
4. [Doctor Fate](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Doctor_Fate) (probably [Kent Nelson](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Kent_Nelson)), DC Comics, from the [*Infinite Fate* set](http://onceuponageek.com/images/drfate_infiniteheroes.jpg)
5. [Doctor Mindbender](http://gijoe.wikia.com/wiki/Dr._Mindbender_(RAH)), *G.I. Joe*, possibly from the [Classic Collection Series 5](http://www.figurerealm.com/actionfigure?action=actionfigure&id=2740)
6. [Doctor Victor von Doom](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Victor_von_Doom_(Earth-616)), Marvel Comics, from [*Marvel Universe* Series 3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004PAKEFM)
7. [Doctor Cornelius Evazan](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cornelius_Evazan), *Star Wars*, from the [Original Trilogy collection](http://www.museumofplay.org/online-collections/1/12/113.1011)
8. [Doctor Hank Pym](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Henry_Pym_(Earth-616)) (as [Yellowjacket](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Yellowjacket)), Marvel Comics, from [*Marvel Universe* Series 3](http://www.hasbro.com/en-us/product/marvel-universe-yellowjacket-with-ant-man:CAE2C03B-19B9-F369-101A-0C9DCD60830F)

8b. [Twiki](http://buckrogers.wikia.com/wiki/Twiki), carrying [Dr. Theopolis](http://buckrogers.wikia.com/wiki/Dr._Theopolis), *Buck Rogers in the 25th Century*, probably [the Mego one](https://www.figurerealm.com/actionfigure?action=actionfigure&id=4852)

9. [Doctor Leonard Samson](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Leonard_Samson_(Earth-616)), Marvel Comics, from [*Marvel Universe* Series 3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004D1IPD6)
10. [Doctor Indiana Jones](http://indianajones.wikia.com/wiki/Indiana_Jones), *Indiana Jones*, possibly from this [Hasbro 2008 series](http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/361362908458?ul_noapp=true&chn=ps&lpid=82)
11. [An Italian doctor](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Doctors), *Assassin's Creed*, from the [*Assassins Creed: Brotherhood* licensed figures](http://www.mjstoy.com/unimax-year-2011-ubisoft-entertainment-game-series-assassins-creed-brotherhood-officially-licensed-inch-tall-poseable-action-figure-doctor-with-syringe-p-2410.html?osCsid=b2618c6d7120570a7c0a0f14090cf0d0)
12. [Cesi "Doc" Eirriss](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cesi_Eirriss), *Star Wars*, from the [Legacy Collection Rebel Pilot Set](http://www.toywiz.com/cwevorebellion2.html)
13. [Doctor Otto Octavius](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Otto_Octavius_(Earth-616)) (aka Doctor Octopus), Marvel Comics, the [Mass Attack version](http://capeandcowlcollectibles.com/marvel-spider-man-mass-attack-doc-ock/)
14. [White Dalek](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Supreme_Dalek_(New_Dalek_Paradigm)) (not actually a doctor), *Doctor Who*, from the [*Remembrance of the Dalek* set](https://forbiddenplanet.com/63322-doctor-who-action-figure-collectors-set-remembrance-of-the-daleks/)

Comment: The Dalek could be a reference to Davros (who had a white Dalek form), AKA **Dr.** Vaso.

Comment: really stuck on that Doc Ock figure; I can't find a single one that has the chest piece...

Comment: [Mass Attack Doc Ock](http://capeandcowlcollectibles.com/?show=single&id=380)

Comment: My money is definitely on [Dr. Evazan, Original Trilogy Collection](http://www.museumofplay.org/online-collections/1/12/113.1011) for 7. The ugly guy from Mos Eisley.

Comment: The Daleks from the paradigm set seem to have black pips, but the one in the photo has gold pips...

Comment: ok, fix the Dalek, added the doc ock link, and swapped in Doctor Evazan; looking for a better image of him from the side just to confirm but looks pretty solid.

Comment: I found [this site that may be origin of the image](http://rumpus-room.tumblr.com/post/13552169783/doctors) (it has the largest size image, and the style matches the rest of their blog), and it has tagged the photo "Doctor Evazan"

Comment: 2. looks like the Fourth Doctor (**Tom** Baker) sans scarf. Definitely not the Sixth Doctor (**Colin** Baker) who had blonde curly hair and a bright, multicoloured coat.

Comment: 2. Maybe the Fourth without scarf, but it seems very strange (scarf is his "Doctor sign"). I think it could be 8th

+. Depending of figure's age, 11 will be some Black Death doctor. So an historical character and no more an Assassin's Creed one.

Comment: #11 is an historical European plague doctor but the action figure is from the AC: Brotherhood set. The video game character is modeled on the historical doctors.

Comment: Well done. Nice catch on Dr. Theopolis. Most miss that one.

Comment: the comments are mostly gone, but I had help on the two Star Wars, the GI Joe, and the Assassinc Creed ones. Also, I'm still very sketchy on #2 I assume The Doctor from *Doctor Who* is in there somewhere but that doesn't look like any of the Doctors.

Comment: I think that the McCoy figure is actually [Spock from the Galaxy Collection](http://www.amazon.com/Star-Trek-Galaxy-Collection-Action/dp/B00262SNBI/) (McCoy's figure from the set had the maroon cadet outfit). [Here's a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q-AHKNSCzXg) of someone playing with it. It's pretty common for those not familiar with Star Trek to call the character "Dr. Spock". The main thing I'm noticing from the picture is that the shoulder has a light reflection (suggesting that the shirt is plastic, not textile) and he has a visible elbow joint.